# How to get Android Market on Archos 70I

Tags: google-play-store, archos-gen7

I have an Archos 70i and am still unable to get Android Market on it. I want to get a flash player and other apps which I believe is available on Android Market. Can anyone help me in simple English, please? I do have Appslib already but this is lacking the apps i want.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to side-load a Market.apk file that's been hacked to work with your device.  This will require root.  You could also load a custom ROM with the Market already on it.  [I recommend searching XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=877).

That said, you won't be able to get Flash unless you have/get 2.2.  [Flash requires Android 2.2+ as well as an ARMv7 or better processor](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/systemreqs/index.html#mobile).  The 70 series is supposed to have an A8 Cortex based on ARMv7, so that part's OK.

Answer (score 0):

As of March 10 you can install the '**ArcTools**' from the **AppsLib**.

This will let you install the **Android Market** - and thus also *Gmail*, *Flash* and all the things which are unavailable otherwise.

Did this yesterday on my **Archos 101** and this worked without problems . I know now have the official Facebook, the TweetCaster program - to name but a few programs I was really missing.

Comment: Edelcom, I loaded it and AppsLib informed me that the eLocity is an unsupported device.

Comment: @fredi: Where you able to install the Android market ? If so, could you please accept an answer ?