# “There are no android phones associated with this account.”

Tags: google-play-store, accounts

I recently bought an eLocity A7 Internet Tablet. I'm unable to download any apps from the Android Market, even though I have a Google account. I keep getting the reason, “There are no android phones associated with this account.”

One fix I've heard of is to get a gmail account and hook up your Android phone number to it, then it will be associated with the account. But the eLocity tablet is not a phone.

Another fix has to do with installing the Android Market apk file, which brings a user to the Android Market. Signing in will associate the device with the account. But I haven't found a reputable link from which to download the app.

Any other ideas?

Comment: @Steve You don't need to edit the question to mark it as answered.  If you associate your StackOverflow and Android Enthusiasts accounts, you will regain control of this question, and can select an answer as the accepted solution (by hitting the checkmark below the answer's vote count) if you wish.

Answer (score 8):

In short, you have a non-Google-approved device.  That's why there are no Google apps on it.  And you can't download from the Market unless you have the Market installed on your device.

There are ways to get the Market on your device anyways, though.  (See [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5685/how-to-get-android-market-on-archos-70i)).  However, none of those ways will have a "reputable link" for you to download.  You're going outside Google and possibly the law, depending on your jurisdiction.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is a very common problem, and I guess the google guys are on it, but so far, no solution.

I bought an Archos tablet and for two days I've been trying to download and install a good browser. I tried every single solution I found in every single forum on line (believe me when I say that it is a very common problem!!!). No luck.

What worked for me was quite simple: I found a website where you can download the same apps and they actually can be downloaded. You don't even need to create an account!! Try it: http://www.freewarelovers.com/android. Maybe you will find what you want. I did.

Good luck!

Comment: The "Google guys" have nothing to fix. See [Matthew Read's answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/9153/981) regarding how the Market works with regards to non-approved devices.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of an Android device being a phone or tablet, I *believe*, that to make use of the core Google apps you will need to tie directly to a Google account.  I am user of a Moto Xoom (wifi only) and this is absolutely true.  So I would suggest adding a Google account with the device (Settigns - Accounts & Sync).

Comment: Kevin, I am unable to actually add any accounts to my device. Clicking on Add Account takes me to a page to add an Exchange account. No other account. No icons to add a Google account.

Comment: I am having the same issue.http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10159/android-sdk-2-1-unable-to-install-app-from-android-market