# Android SDK 2.1: Unable to install app from Android Market on the Emulator

Tags: google-play-store, android-emulator, android-sdk

I am testing the Emulator that comes with Android SDK 2.1, but I am Unable to install app from Android Market.

I made the Login on `www.google.com` but still no success: This is the error message:

> Não há telefones Android associados a esta conta. Faça login com uma conta diferente.
>
> *There are no Android telephones associated to this account. Do Login with a different account.*

Comment: Did you just log into the Market, or did you also add your account to the phone?  Look at `Settings -> Accounts and sync` and see if it's listed.  And by testing the SDK, do you mean the emulator?  We have questions on getting the Market on the emulator, just search :)

Comment: I tried that, but it seems that it want to add an e-mail account. When I type my username@hotmail.com  it tries to connect to hotmail. But gives an error

Comment: You need a Google account.

Comment: +1 good question. I get this even with a Google account logged in on emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Check your system configuration if it is 32-bit or 64-bit processor. Download Android SDK (32-bit or 64-bit) and install it. Also download Eclipse (32-bit or 64-bit) and install it.

Answer (score 0):

The market on the emulator is a special case.

It is also recommended you use a Google Account i.e. you are using username@hotmail.com change to use username@google.com

To reset the account associated with the phone , either clear all google app's cache or do a factory reset. As you are on an emulator just delete that one and create a new one.